# Incrementar margem em pixels no sass

Tags: css, sass

Preciso criar margens, top, right, left e bottom, gostaria de fazer um loop em sass de 0 a 100. CSS final ficaria algo parecido com isso:

```
margem-top: 1px;
margem-top: 2px;

margem-left: 66px;
margem-left: 88px;

margem-bottom: 15px;
margem-bottom: 100px;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não compreendi muito bem o exemplo relacionado a pergunta. Mas você pode fazer um loop percorrendo a sequencia(1 a 100) e um percorrendo as direções (top, right, bottom e left) e criar classes para cada uma das situações.

Ex.

SASS:

```
$_DIRECTIONS: (top right bottom left)

@for $i from 1 through 100
  .margin-#{$i}
    margin: #{$i}px

  @each $direction in $_DIRECTIONS
    .margin-#{$direction}-#{$i}
      margin-#{$direction}: #{$i}px
```

SCSS:

```
$_DIRECTIONS: (top right bottom left);

@for $i from 1 through 100 {
  .margin-#{$i} { margin: #{$i}px; }

  @each $direction in $_DIRECTIONS {
    .margin-#{$direction}-#{$i} { margin-#{$direction}: #{$i}px; }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container margin-top-12 margin-left-15 margin-bottom-88"></div>
```